# Can I return a span in C++? If so, how? (Open to alternatives.)

Tags: c++, guideline-support-library

The project guide for an assignment I've been given specifically barred the use of vectors and strings, but I need to pass a char array of indeterminate size from a function. The use of **span** seems like it *might* be viable for this purpose if I can better understand how it is used. If anyone could recommend a better/different means of passing arrays (aside from strings and vectors) I would love to learn about it.

I have considered generating a scratch file and storing input text there for recall elsewhere in the program, but that seems rather more cumbersome than should be necessary in this case. This program will also be small enough that I *could* do everything in main, but that also shouldn't be necessary.

What I would like to do is to be able to call a function like this:

```
span<char> getSpan(){
    char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
    span<char> spanOut{ arr };
    return spanOut;
}
```

and then print the contents of spanOut from main:

```
int main() {
    // Some Code...
    printSpan = getSpan();
    std::cout << printSpan;
}
```

Ideally, the result of the above code would be to have `ABC` printed to the terminal.

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::string`, then why not simply use a vector of  `char`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] for an overview of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am still not really sure *what* your assignment is. You say, you need to pass an array of indefinite size - but the your example shows only a definite case. Am I right to assume, that you want to determine the size of the array at runtime? If that is indeed the case, I am pretty sure, your teacher/prof wants you to use `dynamically allocated memory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [Anonymous Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483401/anonymous-anonymous) was [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154445/can-i-return-a-span-in-c-if-so-how-open-to-alternatives#comment102692380_58154445), the instructor wanted me to use dynamically allocated memory. I had been getting too "clever" for my own good, and missing the obvious in favor of complexity. Thank you, [L.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9716597/l-f), for your [excellent breakdown of span](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154492/12138045) :)

Answer (score 2):

`span` is a non-owning view.  It is similar to pointers and references.  When `getSpan` returns, the local array `arr` no longer exists.  The returned span points to this nonexistent array, and accessing it results in undefined behavior.  This is analogous to the dangling pointer problem.

You can return a `span` if you make sure that the storage still exists after the function returns:

```
auto getSpan()
{
    static char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }; // note: static
    return span(arr);
}
```

Note that this problem is present as long as you return something with pointer semantics (i.e., non-owning) — iterators, references, etc.

Comment: So the root of the issue persists - the array stops existing.
Would there be any issues with using a static char array for user inputs?

Comment: @GarrettYates Should be OK, as long as you don't reuse the array.  Please provide a [mre] for more detail.